# Can't access value of key in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using the [Rspotify gem](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify) (it's a wrapper for the Spotify API), and I'm trying to access the url of the first image in the below array:

```
[# < RSpotify::Artist: 0x007f8558147050 @images = [{
    "height" => 640, "url" => "https://i.scdn.co/image/cb080366dc8af1fe4dc90c4b9959794794884c66", "width" => 640
  }, {
    "height" => 320, "url" => "https://i.scdn.co/image/6bd672a0f33705eda4b543c304c21a152f393291", "width" => 320
  }, {
    "height" => 160, "url" => "https://i.scdn.co/image/085ae2e76f402468fe9982851b51cf876e4f20fe", "width" => 160
  }]
]
```

I'm able to get to the following using `artist.images.first`, but I can't access the URL in it by chaining anything (e.g. `.url` , `["url"]` , `("url")` , `[:url]` ):

```
{"height"=>640, "url"=>"https://i.scdn.co/image/cb080366dc8af1fe4dc90c4b9959794794884c66", "width"=>640}
```

Here's my controller:

```
def search
  unless params[:artist][:artist_name].blank?
    artist = params[:artist][:artist_name]
    @artists = RSpotify::Artist.search(artist)
    render 'pages/profile'
  end
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<h1> Search Results </h1>
<ul>
 <% @artists.each do |artist| %>
   <li> <%= artist.images.first['url'] %> | <%= artist.name %> </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you get for this? `artist.images.first.class`

Comment: `<%= artist.images.first.url %>` it seems to be not a hash, it’s how `inspect` is implemented. What error message do you receive btw?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon It says it's a Hash. @mudasobwa I get the following: undefined method `url' for #<Hash:0x000000036aea70>.

Answer (score 2):

Using artist.images.first['url'] should solve it.

The following code worked for me:

```
require 'rspotify'

artist = RSpotify::Artist.search('Arctic Monkeys').first

puts artist.images.first['url']
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. I updated my post with my controller and view code.

Comment: You could get this error if the artist has no images. Add a safety check like `if artist.images.any?`

Comment: The artist has images. It's the same artist that I included in my post.